# Type-safe approaches for handling reference data in Java applications

Tags: java, architecture, enums, reference, lookup

For possibly no other good reason at this point in time other that 'we've always done it like this', how are new systems being architected to use reference data used to represent state codes?

For example, a Case may have 2 valid states, 'Open' or 'Closed'. Historically I've seen many systems where these valid values would be stored in a database table containing this reference data, and referred to as a code type ('CaseStatus'), and each valid value has a 'code' value (eg 'OPN') and a decode or display value that is used when the value is needed to be displayed to a user (in this case 'Open').

If developing a Java based system today, from a code point of view with type safety, we would define an Enum like this:

```
public enum CaseStatus{
    Open("OPN"),
    Closed("CLS");

    private String codeValue;

    private CaseStatus(String codeValue){
        this.codeValue = codeValue;
    }
}
```

This is great solely from the view of the source code, the Enum enforces type-safety with a restricted list of valid values, but by itself there is no representation of this code type or it's valid values in the database. If there are users of the data who run adhoc reports directly against the database, they need a way to look up decoded values for 'OPN', 'CLS'. Historically this would have been done using a reference table containing the codetype, the codes and their decode values.

It seems odd that we continue to use these state code values as '3 letter codes', where the motivation at this point is no longer because we need to save space in the database ('OPN' vs 'Open' is hardly a great optimization anyway).

What other approaches have people used or seen on recent systems they have worked on? Do you maintain the reference data only in the database, only in code, or in both places, and if you maintain it in both, what approaches do you use to keep the two in sync?

Comment: if you want a reference table you are realizing a manytomany relation which is a different concept than an Enum class or a enum sql type column.

Comment: By reference table I mean a table of 'reference data', static, lookup data, that won't change during runtime. So my question is, what is the best approach to refer to and use this data in both a typesafe way from the source code, as well as store it using a sensible approach in a datastore, such as (but not necessarily) a RDBMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if there are only two possible values, and it is not possible to expect them to develop into a larger number (as in your example of `open`/`closed`), I would probably define a `status_open` column as `BOOLEAN` or `SMALLINT` (0/1) or `CHAR` (Y/N).

When the universe of status is bigger (or may increase to more than two values), I would use a surrogate key. While saving a few bytes is hardly an optimization, indexing and joining `CHAR` valued columns is more expensive than indexing and joining `INTEGER` columns. While I don't have a metric on the issue of `INTEGER` vs `CHAR(3)`, I would suppose that for this case the difference would not be as big as in the case of INTEGER vs CHAR(50).

However, an disadventage that I find in small CHAR abbreviations is that sometimes it is difficult to find meaningful values. Suppose that you have an status of *"broken - replacement has been ordered"*, does it help if I call it "BRO"? Is it better than calling it `3`?

On the other hand, even when it is not required by the model, I found convenient adding a short `VARCHAR` column on `status`, for describing what each mnemonic or surrogate key means. (After the model grows, it becomes quite difficult to remember all of them!)

My implementation (with due exceptions in particular cases) would likely be:

On the Java side, the enum, as you defined it. (Even for boolean-like values, sometimes it helps having different enums for each value, particularly if there are methods taking several of those values as parameter. Methods with a long list of parameters of the same type are a recipe for disaster).

On the SQL side:

```
CREATE TABLE status (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  description VARCHAR(40)
)

CREATE TABLE entity (
 ...
 status_id INTEGER REFERENCES status(id)
)

INSERT INTO status VALUES (0,'Closed');
INSERT INTO status VALUES (1,'Open');
INSERT INTO status VALUES (2,'Broken - replacement has been ordered');
```

Comment: Re. char abbreviations, like BRO, vs an id like 3, I think we've been using short char code abbreviations like this for historical reasons for so long that we're forgotten why we used to do this, but I'd argue that OPN is more useful for code readability and maintainability that 0. I could guess what OPN represents, but I can't guess what 0 is unless I go an look it up?

Comment: I do like your example of the code values defined in a table and then reference them by id, but to the point in my previous comment, how would you avoid developers having to refer to a CaseStatus as one of either 0, 1, or 2 as the valid values, which arguably don't have any human recognizable meaning? Would you represent these in code as an Enum where the value of each enum value is 0,1, or 2, but then how do you keep the source of the Enum in sync with the values in the table? If a code fix adds a new code, would you add it in both places, use code generation, or some other approach?

Comment: Java developers would reference it as `CaseStatus.OPEN` (in view, model and service layers), then they would never meet `0` while implementing the business logic, and benefit from compiler-enforced type safety. In the DAOs they would use `CaseStatus.OPEN.id` or some automatic solution (such as hibernate custom types).

Comment: Of course, there will be "code duplication" in the sense that `0` will be an argument in the constructor call for `CaseStatus.OPEN`, and it will also be the primary key of a row with `description='Open'`.
If you are not adding new status day after day, I think that synchronization issues can be dealt by communicating between the development team and the team in charge of the database, without need for a code generation tool (or a script that updates the status table with the new values).

Answer (score 1):

One solution I've encountered is to use a materialized view in the database to dynamically recalculate the denormalized relation. In a document based database you would probably store the `CaseStatus` as a `String`. Finally, you might use an ORM tool to store `CaseStatus` as an `Object` but in the cases I'm familiar with the reference data is stored in the database (if you store it in code then it requires a build and deployment to production, along with additional testing for the *release*).

Comment: Can you elaborate on use of the materialized view? If the reference data is in a table and not changing (because it is static reference data), what does the materialized view do? Is this used by the application, or by other users of the same database, like in my example, people running adhoc reports against the data (and needing a way to decode the status codes)?

Comment: A [materialized view](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Materialized_view) is a way to optimize the [*denormalization*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization) (what you're calling a decode). And it can be used in either case, and I have seen them used both ways.

Comment: Ah, ok, so would you use a separate view for each of the reference data/code category types? e.g. in my example I have CaseStatus, would there be a 'case status code view' that would provide the mapping between this reference data and anyone that needs to refer to it, e.g. the app or a report? Or did you build something that provides this feature generically, for all types of lookup data (assuming it's all coming from the same table?)

Comment: @KevinHooke The answer depends on context. How is the first not generic? Typesafety should depend on the object model, the values stored in the database depends on the data model. You can optimize both in a number of ways. Regardless, there is no silver bullet.